# Thumbnails are being created in background thread but not displayed on initialization

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-cursoradapter, universal-image-loader

When I start my application I have a Asynctask kick off which looks for any new videos and creates the thumbnails and adds them to a database. I later use the Universal Image Loader to find and set that bitmap to the view. My problem is when I start my application for the first time all the data is loaded to the database but nothing shows up in the gridview. I don't even think the adapter gets called. However, when I start the application once all the data is loaded the gridview shows all the thumbnails and it runs smoothly.

I was wondering why this happens and what I could do to fix this problem. My code is below

AsyncTask

```
private class DataEntry extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, GridviewData>{
GridviewData dataentry;
DataEntry(GridviewData gridviewdata){
    this.dataentry = gridviewdata;

}

@Override
protected GridviewData doInBackground(Void... params) {

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {

        String videoid = cursor.getString(columnindexid);
        String videopath = cursor.getString(columnindexdata);

        int result = dataentry.findVideoID(videoid);
        if (result == 1){
            Bitmap bmthumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videopath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            if (bmthumb != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmthumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] thumbnailBitmapBytes = stream.toByteArray();
            dataentry.addVideoinfo(videoid, videopath, thumbnailBitmapBytes);
            }
        }

        if (result == 0){
            Log.i(TAG, "Cursor wasn't processed, no getcount");
        }
        if(result == 2){
            //there is data already there
        }

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    Log.i(TAG, "After dowhile loop");
    cursor.close();

    return dataentry;

}

    }
```

Base Image Loader

```
public class SqliteImageDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader {

private static final String SCHEME_DB = "db";
private static final String DB_URI_PREFIX = SCHEME_DB + "://";
Cursor cursor;

public SqliteImageDownloader(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected InputStream getStreamFromOtherSource(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
    if (imageUri.startsWith(DB_URI_PREFIX)) {
        String path = imageUri.substring(19);
        cursor = entry.BitFinder(path); 
        byte[] imageData = cursor.getBlob(0);

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
    } else {
        return super.getStreamFromOtherSource(imageUri, extra);
    }
}
}
```

Cursor Adapter

```
class VideoAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
Cursor curs;
Context context; 
public VideoAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    this.context = context;
    this.curs = c;

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    String filepath = curs.getString(videopathindex);

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("db://VideoandThumbs" + filepath, holder.imageview);

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View eachgrid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eachgrid, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.imageview = (ImageView) eachgrid.findViewById(R.id.Imageview1);
    eachgrid.setTag(holder);
    return eachgrid;        
}

    }
```

Comment: you should use cache for that..

Comment: Instead of using a database? What are the advantages of cache over database?

Comment: it gives you fast result and store temporary file from server..

Comment: Do you know of any good examples I could reference?

Comment: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/31/loading-caching-and-displaying-images-in-android-part-1/